# mac desktop vs Desktop

Tags: macos, terminal

In mac I can see that the Desktop folder is located under home.

```
cd ~
ls
```

and I will see the Desktop folder.

However if I type cd ~/desktop (lowercase) it will also end up in the desktop folder. But I can't find what is the nature of *desktop*. Is it a link or an alias to *Desktop*?

Comment: Non-development-oriented questions are in general better asked on [su], and for Apple platform specifically on [apple.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HFS+ is the default format for Mac OS X. It is case-preserving but not case-sensitive, that is it knows when you use upper and lower case characters in a filename/directory.

Many shell-based applications automatically assume case sensitive (where desktop and Desktop are completely different directories) and break when you don't have a case-sensitive file system, as you've found.

It is possible to use case-sensitive file systems on Mac OS X - there's even a HFS+ (case sensitive) option, but it can only be defined when you format a drive, and it's not recommended for your boot volume.